# How do I change font size and wieght in Visual Studio 2013 Lightswitch Html screen control?

Tags: html, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have added a Text Box to a screen for some content that I entered via the "Edit PostRender Code" in a HTML AddEdit screen in a Visual Studio 2013 Lightswitch application. How do I change font size and weight here as well as in other control labels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use jQuery to manipulate the element

```
myapp.SomeScreen.showMyControl_postRender(element, contentItem){
    $(element).css({
        'font-size' : '12px',
        'font-width' : '300'
    });
}
```